# Maya creating shader with cmds does not appear in hypershade

Tags: maya

using maya 2014/2015 creating a shader like so:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
my_shader = cmds.createNode('lambert', n='mine')
```

will create this result.
[image]

anybody knows how to get that shader to be reflected in the hypershade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shaders are a slightly different node type:

`cmds.shadingNode('lambert', asShader=1)`

You'll also need to create a `shadingEngine` node, what we usually know as ShaderGroups or SG`s:

`cmds.shadingNode('shadingEngine', asUtility=1)`

and connect the `.outColor` of the shader to the `.surfaceShader` attribute of the SG.  The SG node is actually a subclass of a Maya set, and to assign objects or faces to it use the `sets` command.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer for completeness:

In some cases (namely `ShaderFx` shaders) you need to connect the material to the scene's `defaultShaderList1` node's next available plug.

```
import maya.cmds as mc

material = mc.shadingNode('lambert', asShader=True)
shading_engine = mc.sets(name="%sSG" % material, empty=True, renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True)
mc.connectAttr('%s.outColor' % material, '%s.surfaceShader' % shading_engine)
mc.connectAttr('%s.msg'%material, ':defaultShaderList1.s', na=True)
```